# Monitor health of Beanstalk app which doesn't receive requests?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

I want to deploy my python app which monitors cryptocurrency data via websockets, but doesn't receive any http requests like a web server.

And how do I monitor the health of it? Since there are no HTTP requests coming in so I can't look at requests or how long the app takes to respond.

Ideally I could monitor network packets (which would include the websockets) or logs for errors. Is there a way for beanstalk to do this?

Or is beanstalk just not built for apps like this?

Comment: You could run a lightweight web server (like Flask in the case of Python) alongside your websocket monitoring script. This server would primarily serve as a health check target for the Elastic Beanstalk environment. You don't necessarily have to serve any meaningful content. For instance, you can just return a 200 OK status for any health check requests.